# Render state in another component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to display current user name in a different component but It's not working, what am I doing wrong ?

Here's where I'm initialising the username (App.js)

```js
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logged_in: localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false,
      username: ''
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.logged_in) {
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/user/current_user/', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          this.setState({ username: json.username });
          console.log(json.username);
        });

    }
  }
  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={First} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Projects} />
          <Route path="/menu" component={MenuH} />
          <Route path ="/createProject" component={CreateP} />
          <Route path ="/connect" component={Newacount} />
          <Route component={Notfound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
...
```

And here's how I'm calling it in a different component (projects)

```js
{this.state.username}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good discussion about [How to pass component via react router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105).

When following the discussion, you code will look like:

```
<div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <!-- Pass username as props here -->
          <Route path="/your-route" render={()=><Projects username={this.state.username}/>} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
</div>
```

And into your `Projects` component, you retrieve it with `this.props.username`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Projects component does not have access to the state in `App`.

You should do this with a state manager like [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, you cannot just access the parent's state directly in all the child components, 
you have to send the parents state down to the child components as a prop to access them.

In scenario like this where you want to use one state in all of your child components the good thing is to use Redux, it will provide you a global state which will be accessible in all of your components. 
Also you can solve this problem with React's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 0):

try sending state as props for child and access it from child! or to access state directly u can use redux store or context api from react!

```
<Route path="/home" render={()=><Home username={this.state.username} />} />
```